How to programatically trigger a flow on a flow builder on shopware6
I have implemented a flow that should trigger based on when the delivery status changes.
in this flow i have a condition that that reflects "order with tag" is one of "a tag which i have created e.g tagger"
i then have written a command to tag orders that have their delivery status as shipped within a specific period of time
$criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addAssociation('deliveries.stateMachineState');
        $criteria->addAssociation('orderCustomer');
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('deliveries.stateMachineState.technicalName', 'Shipped'));

 $oneWeekAgo = new \DateTime('-1 days');
        $criteria->addFilter(new RangeFilter('orderDateTime', [
            RangeFilter::GTE => $oneWeekAgo->format(DATE_ATOM)
        ]));


//my tag method

  private function tagOrder(Context $context, string $orderId, string $tagId): void
    {
        $this->orderRepository->update([
            [
                'id' => $orderId,
                'tags' => [
                    ['id' => $tagId]
                ]
            ]
        ], $context);
    }

// and then called

  $this->tagOrder($context, $order->getId(), $tagId);

code works as expected, tagging the orders i need tagged.
But i have noticed because of the the trigger from the flow which is set to "status reached / order delivery/ status / shipped
which then send s a delivery mail (very important)
the flow only gets executed when the delivery status changes not surprisingly.
How can i get the the same flow or a flow of any kind to be triggered programatically after i am done tagging my orders.
please have in mind the delivery mail needs to be sent when the flow or flow of any kind is triggered.
I have also heard of a flowexecutor, but how can this be used?
Thanks

I got it working by creating my custom event trigger and adding it to my existing flow.
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-trigger.html
i extended to the following interfaces
MailAware  -- gives you access to MailRecipientStruct method and then I could use the send email action on the backend.
OrderAware --- Access to the orderid
SalesChannelAware - sales channel id
and BusinessEventInterface
I also added the needed action "send email" on the backend to send my delivery mails
this is my basic explaination of how i fixed it.
